# React Django state lost in continuous refresh of page

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs

I'm developing a web app with Django and React, I build the structure of the page on a react component and it looks like it works.
I have a to do list component, 
I have a state that holds title and items of the to do list. 
then when the list is completed I wanted to post the to do list to the database.

The issue that I'm facing is the following:
- Load `http://localhost:8000/`
- click on add item
- react renders the new empty field for the new item. it last a second, the page refreshes, the link becomes

`http://localhost:8000/?title=&dateCreation=&toDoItem=&when=&note=&toDoItem=&when=&note=`

and the page loses the state and everything is like at the beginning of the state

```
state = {
        toDoList:{
            title:"",
            dateCreation:"",
            toDoItems:[
                {itemName:"",when: "", note:""},
            ]
        }
    }

addItemHandler = () => {
    const toDoList = {...this.state.toDoList}
    const toDoItems = [...this.state.toDoList.toDoItems]
    toDoItems.push({itemName:"",when: "", note:""})
    toDoList.toDoItems = toDoItems
    return this.setState({toDoList: toDoList})
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved changing the jsx of the component, before this handler was adding components inside a form HTMLelement, I just changed the form tag with a div and solved the issue.

Before

```
<form>
  <input>
  {addItems}
</form>
```

After

```
<div>
  <input>
  {addItems}
</div>
```